# What is the correct style to indicate that there is nothing to return?

Tags: c++

I store objects using an unordered_map of unordered_maps:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, WorldObject>> _worldObjects;
```

I retrieve an object using this function:

```
   WorldObject& objectAtLocation(int x,int y){
        if(_worldObjects.find(x)!=_worldObjects.end() && _worldObjects[x].find(y)!= _worldObjects[x].end()){
            //Contains an object
        }else{
            //Does not contain an object at that location. What should I return ?
        }
    }
```

If there is no object stored at x,y, then what is the correct way to indicate that in this function ?

For example, I could modify the function like this:

```
//return value indicating presence of object, output the variable that data is copied into.
bool objectAtlocation(int x,int y,WorldObject& output);
```

Any suggestions ?

EDIT: Is it better to just use pointers ?

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, WorldObject*>> _worldObjects;
```

so I can do:

```
WorldObject* objectAtLocation(int x,int y){
    WorldObject* result = nullptr;

    if(_worldObjects.find(x)!=_worldObjects.end() && _worldObjects[x].find(y)!= _worldObjects[x].end()){
        //Contains an object
        result = _worldObjects[x][y];
    }else{
        //Does not contain an object at that location. Returning nullptr:
    }

    return result;
}
```

EDIT: It is not exceptional for there not to be an object at a coordinate (x,y). Therefore I do not need to throw an exception. I would just like to indicate that there is nothing at that location.

Can you provide sample code with your answer, as I am new to C++, and may not fully understand from your comment?

Comment: How about pointer?

Comment: @songyuanyao - good timing! I was just thinking that - Updated the question - what do you think ?

Comment: If the failed path is an exceptional event, throw an exception? Or use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (coming in C++17, could use [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) or [Boost optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) meanwhile)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It isn't an exceptional event - I just want to indicate that there is nothing stored there.

Comment: You don't need to change the type of map. You can get the address of the elements like `result = &_worldObjects[x][y];`

Comment: The most common is probably using pointers and returning nullptr, but e.g. in Qt you see functions returning objects (not references though) which can be empty. If you expect your function to only be called with valid coordinates, where there always should be an object, you could throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

The "Standard C++ Way" would be to return iterators. <strike>If nothing is found that matches your search criteria, you would return `_worldObjects.end()`.</strike> (EDIT: This won't work in your case, I misread how you were using the container)

If your container is complex and does not suit returning iterators, you can return *pointers* to your objects, returning `nullptr` if the object was not found.

EDIT:

Adapting the code sample from your question edit:

```
WorldObject* objectAtLocation(int x,int y){
    WorldObject *result = nullptr;

    const auto xIter = _worldObjects.find(x)
    if(xIter !=_worldObjects.end()){
        const auto yIter = xIter->find(y);
        if (yIter != xIter->end()){
            //Contains an object
            result = &(*yIter);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Don't really recommend pointers, unless you want to get into subtle ownership issues.

Comment: @Karl Nicoll - Can you give an example of returning the iterator ?

Comment: Iterator doesn't work here. If fails returns `std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, WorldObject>>::iterator`, then what should be returned when found? A `std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, WorldObject>>::iterator` can't get the element directly.

Comment: I don't fully understand either - what should be returned when the object is found and not found ? How will I know the item was not found ?

Comment: @John - I don't think it would be suitable for your case. Nested containers don't really suit iterator return values, as you can't easily compare to `myContainer.end()` to check if the value exists. I would probably recommend the pointer way.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper - I don't think there are any ownership issues here. The container would own the objects. You could easily clarify any ownership ambiguity using standard smart pointers (e.g. shared_ptr/weak_ptr, unique_ptr, intrusive pointers, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, in my opinion there is no reason to do something overly complicated. So I think that your own suggestion is fine.

Otherwise you could return a pointer and then check then return null when you find nothing.

Alternatively, you could implement a nullable class (which can be a template or a class that you inherit from) that would allow you to check whether your instance is a null object.

Still, you could define a "default" state to your object that would mean null and you could check against that, so whenever you do not find anything you could return a reference to the null object. The null object could be static or not.